# text element not moving with jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a text element within an SVG that I have applied jQuery ui draggable to. Whenever I try to drag it around, the top and left CSS attributes change as you would expect, however, the element itself does not move - it just stays where it is.

This defys everything I understand about positioning. It seems as though it is just ignoring the 'top' and 'left' rules altogether.

However, the plot thickens.

I have also applied ui-draggable to an image within the same svg and it's working fine for that. When I drag it around, it moves as expected.

Most intriguingly, if I drag some text, then it won't move however if I then move the image, then the text suddenly moves to where I had tried to drag it to!

Can someone provide any insight as to what is going on here please?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<svg id="k" width="220" height="440" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <image xlink:href="http://u.r.l/media/1353519179-9178.png" width="220" height="440" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" style="position: relative; left: 2px; top: 3px;" class="ui-draggable" transform="rotate(0,112,223) translate(2,3)"></image>
    <text id="svgtxt" x="0" y="0" style="position: relative; left: 101px; top: 118px;" class="ui-draggable" transform="rotate(0,101,118) translate(101,118)">Hello, world!</text>
</svg>
```

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
// ...

$("#k image").draggable({
    refreshPositions : true
});

// Make the text element draggable
$("#k text").draggable({
    refreshPositions : true
});

// ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svg `text` element doesn't do anything with `position`, because it adheres to the svg rendering model, not the CSS box model. For a list of properties supported in svg content, see the [svg specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/propidx.html).

You can set `position` on the entire <svg> fragment if it's inline in html, because in that case it's laid out by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `position` css attribute , it will not accept `top` and `left`.

> An element is said to be positioned if its 'position' property has a
>   value other than 'static'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme

Comment: The text element has a position of 'relative'

Comment: why are you setting position, top and left before initializing the draggable??